# Trying an install of ubuntu from flash drive

Tags: system-installation

Trying an install of Ubuntu to a brand new desktop (no OS preinstalled) with an [Asus a320M-K motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-A320M-K/HelpDesk_Manual/) from a flash drive but only getting a DOS prompt. Autorun won't run!! Checking the BIOS boot sequence, it seem to be offering two Ubuntu options, one with UEFI. How do I resolve this problem?

Other components:
[AMD Athlon 200ge](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-athlon-200ge) with Radion graphics
8gb DDR4 RAM
WD 1TB HDD

Comment: There is no autorun, that is trying to run it from Windows. You use your UEFI one time boot menu, often f10 or f12 to boot flash drive. Chose the UEFI boot option for flash drive and you should get grub menu. What brand/model system & what video card/chip? If it does not boot, did you create flash drive correctly? UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formatted flash drive partition & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media
 &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: New desktop with AMD Athlon 200ge with  Radion graphics on a Asus a320M-K MB. 8gb DDR4 Ram. WD 1T hard drive.  I'm thinking it's some setting in the BIOS that's causing it not to boot. Will also try redoing flash drive.

Comment: Did you verify the downloaded ISO with its checksum https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 before creating the LiveUSB to install with? Choose UEFI; get your cellphone ready and if anything extraordinary happens, take a picture so you can describe it accurately later.

Comment: Ubuntu is installed and up and running!  Thanks to all who helped me through it.